# Makefile - up to date rule which is not a file

Tags: makefile, dependencies, rules

Considering this (very) simple Makefile,

```
all: a b
    @echo done
a:
    touch $@
b:
    touch $@
```

I didn't get the behaviour I expected.

In fact, I wish my rule "all" to be executed only if one of its depencies isn't up to date.

However on first $ make I get

```
touch a
touch b
done
```

And on others

```
done
```

I undenstand that "up to date" normally qualify a file but...
Is there any way to have rule "all" considered up to date when all its dependies are ?

Thanks a lot,

ps: I know the trick $ touch all, but that's not the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  If the target does not exist then make will always run the recipe.

There are hacky ways that your `all` recipe could check to see if any of the prerequisites had been built and behave differently if so.  At least, if you're using GNU make.

ETA:

One way would be to add a `$(eval BUILT = 1)` to each target, then in the `all` target you can see if `BUILT` is set.  This requires a moderately recent version of GNU make:

```
BUILT =

all: a b
        @[ -n '$(BUILT)' ] && echo done
a:
        touch $@ $(eval BUILT = 1)
b:
        touch $@ $(eval BUILT = 1)
```

Comment: What could be those "hacky ways" ?